# Small passive speakers?

Tags: small, speakers

Hi crowd,

I'm looking for small (probably better passive) speakers for a multi-channel (16 channels twice) audio installation. I intend to mount them on a wall. Any suggestions?

cheers,
Julian

Answer (score 1):

You can buy naked speakers from a lot of different electronics supply companies. It might be a good way to go for you, because they'll be very cheap. The down-side is that they won't have any kind of housing to speak of, and you may have to do some soldering (or at least get some clip leads) to cable them up.

As an example, here's what www.allelectronics.com offers: http://www.allelectronics.com/make-a-store/category/580/Speakers/1.html

I've ordered from this company before, and have been happy with their service. There are plenty of other places you can order from though.

Comment: thanks, doing all the soldering myself of course is also an option. however even there, in my experience, quality differs widely...

Comment: @Julian - yeah, it certainly can. with passive speakers though, you're relying on the amplification system more than the speakers themselves.

Comment: the cabinets are just important for the sound as the speakers are. don't be surprised if you can't hear what you expected without cabinets..

Comment: @georgi.m - true, but more for the low and low mid frequencies if i understand it correctly. you don't get the best reproduction of those ranges with smaller speakers to begin with, so it's probably less of an issue for the application Julian's talking about. i could be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

Hi
I have used and very much like the speakers from a company called Audica. They are a UK based company and the communication I have had with them has been extremely helpful.
The website address is www.audicapro.co.uk

I have seen their products used in churches, stores, restaurants etc and I've been impressed whenever I see / hear them.

Hope this helps.